# In a gravitational wave, why is the effect on path length due to the change in path negligible?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

This is about Example 16.1 of Hartle's Gravity book, which considers a wave traveling along the $z$-direction given by $$ds^2=-dt^2+(1+f(t-z))dx^2+(1-f(t-z))dy^2+dz^2,$$
where $f(t-z)\ll1$.

Of this wave, he wants to calculate distance $L$ between two points at $x=0$ and at $x=L_*$ (to see how $L$ compares to the Euclidean distance, $L_*$). To do this, he considers a path along the $x$-axis, setting $dt=dy=dz=0$, and calculating $$L=\int{ds}=\int^{L_{*}}_0(1+f(t-z))^{1/2}dx\approx L_*(1+\frac{1}{2}f(t-z)).$$

But this is the length of a path along the $x$-axis, which is not a geodesic in our metric. (Because the metric changes in $z$, a slightly curved path with non-zero $z$ should be shorter, right?) Therefore, this $L$ that was calculated is not the actual distance. 
Intuitively, I think that the distance correction you get from this path perturbation in $z$ should be second order in $f$ at least, but how do you show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because geodesics are an extremum of the length functional. That is (with some abuse of notation), a geodesic $\gamma$ satisfies

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\gamma} L = 0.$$

Hence when you change $\gamma$ by something that is order $f$, its length will change with (at most) order $f^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I also explicitly showed it by calculating that the perturbation $\delta z\propto (\frac{df}{dz})^2$, but this is much faster :)